# I would like to identify the airplane in this photo

Tags: identification, aircraft

My Grandfather was an airplane owner in the early 1940s.  This picture was taken between 1941-1946 from what we believe.  I would like to know the make and model of aircraft so I can model it.  Any help would be wonderful
Thanks[image]

Comment: Welcome to History SE. Nice first answer. Maybe you want to try also at https://aviation.stackexchange.com, which seem to have a pretty good record at it (https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-identification). There is no problem with posting the same question in other sites, as long as it remains on-topic (and it seems good for both sites). PS: If you get an answer in aviation, it would be nice to leave a link to it here; you can answer your own question.

Comment: Which country was the photograph taken in?

Comment: If the picture was taken in the US, then you could search for the partial registration number (showing on the wing in the picture) in the [US Civil Aircraft Register](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N2.html) to get a short list of possibilities.

Comment: @JohnDallman - It would be nice to have official word, but I was operating on the basis it was the US. That is I believe the only country that spells "airplane" without the "o", and was also about the only country making airplanes during the period in question that weren't designated for that country's army. The suits and hats are kind of screaming "USA" to me as well, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks for all of the information.  Yes this is the US.  In fact Vernon County Wisconsin.  My Grandfather was a shoe salesman and wanted to start selling in other states under the Red Goose name.  This was short lived as he ended up with cancer from we can tell and died in 1946.  He is the dapper gentleman in the middle.  My next step is to model this aircraft.  Thanks again for all of the responses.  What a wonderful site.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N14.html scroll down to NC64xx — it’s probably one of these.

Comment: Please remember that, if you find an answer that solves your question, you should mark it as "Accepted" to make it easier to others to see and also to thank the author. It is a little mark just under the downward facing icon.

Answer (score 8):

Just a guess... it looks like a [Cessna DC-6B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_DC-6):

[image: Cessna DC-6B]

Comment: That looks very possible. According to the [US Civil Aircraft Register](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N14.html), a Cessna DC-6B carried the registration NC6444

Comment: Yes this is probably it. Silly me was looking at aircraft from the 30's and 40's; this one first flew in 1929, so I never found it. According [to the website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_DC-6),  there were only about 24 of them made (4 of which were impressed by the Air Force in '42).